# If we knew Taylor series of $f(x)$ is it possible to get Taylor series of $f^{-1}(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

If we knew Taylor series of $f(x)$ is it possible to get Taylor series of $f^{-1}(x)$?

Suppose,

> $$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots$$

Then

> $$f^{-1}(x)=?$$

If possible,how do we get it?

*Easiest would be to expand at $x=a_0$*

Comment: Perhaps looking at Lagrange's Identity for the inverse would be a good place to start.

Comment: Expanded at what point? $x = a_0$ might be the easiest, if it is possible.

Comment: Yes that will be probably easy @Arthur

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What we want is all possible derivatives of $f^{-1}$ at $x = a_0$. We can get those from using that $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$ and using the chain rule. First the constant term is clearly $0$, since $f^{-1}(a_0) = 0$. Differentiating once, we get
$$
[f(f^{-1}(x))]' = [x]'\\
{f^{-1}}'(x)f'(f^{-1}(x)) = 1\\
{f^{-1}}'(a_0)f'(f^{-1}(a_0)) = 1\\
{f^{-1}}'(a_0) = \frac1{f'(0)} = \frac1{a_1}
$$
For the second term, we differentiate once more:
$$
[{f^{-1}}'(x)f'(f^{-1}(x))]' = [1]'\\
{f^{-1}}''(x)f'(f^{-1}(x)) + ({f^{-1}}'(x))^2f''(f^{-1}(x)) = 0\\
{f^{-1}}''(a_0)f'(f^{-1}(a_0)) + ({f^{-1}}'(a_0))^2f''(f^{-1}(a_0)) = 0\\
{f^{-1}}''(a_0) = -\frac{\frac{1}{a_1^2}\cdot 2a_2}{a_1} = -\frac{2a_2}{a_1^3}
$$
and we can keep going, at least in theory, getting
$$
f^{-1}(x) = \frac1{a_1}(x-a_0) - \frac{a_2}{a_1^3}(x-a_0)^2 + \cdots
$$

So, assuming the Taylor series for the inverse exists (which so far amounts to $a_1\neq 0$, and since ${f^{-1}}^{(n)}(x)$ in the $n$'th differentiation always appears only together with $f'(f^{-1}(x))$ as a factor, $a_1 = 0$ seems to me like the only thing that would ever go wrong), there is at least one way to find all the coefficients. I'm sure there are more efficient ways, or that someone else has found a general form for these terms (or at the very least carried this calculation further than the second degree).

Comment: Really a great answer @Arthur

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x^3$, then the Taylor series of $f$ around $x_=0$ is

$f(x)=0+0 \cdot x+0 \cdot x^2+1 \cdot x^3+0 \cdot x^4 +....$.

But $f^{-1}$ is not differentiable at $x_0=0$, hence the Taylor series of $f^{-1}$ does not exist !

Comment: Now how about $x^3 + x$?

Answer (score -1):

Let be Taylor expansion of $f$ near $a\in R$, that is
$$f(x)=f(a)+\frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\cdots+\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n+R_{n+1}(x)$$
Next, let find $f^{-1}(x)$, to do it recll multinomial theorem for case $n=-1$,
$$f^{-1}(x)=\left(f(a)+\frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\cdots+\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n+R_{n+1}(x)\right)^{-1}$$
How to use multinomial theorem in negative exponents is shonw [in this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279621/multinomial-theorem-for-negative-exponents)
Wikipaedia article is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)

Comment: $$f^{-1}(x)\neq \frac{1}{f(x)}$$ Rather, if$$f(x)=y$$ then$$f^{-1}(y)=x$$

Comment: this is -1-order derivative or inverse function ? -understood what  mean

Comment: Inverse function